# Objdump to tell if binary was built on Redhat or Suse

Tags: redhat, suse, objdump, readelf

Is there a switch in objdump or readelf which can tell if an ELF binary was built on Redhat or SUSE? I only have binary and no source code.

Is there any other way (like strings command or nm) that could I could use if objdump/readelf isn't useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely. You may make a guess based on the required libraries from `readelf -a /path/to/binary | grep -E '(NEEDED|@GLIBC_)'` what the (highest) required glibc version is.

Maybe, in case there are enough strings left in the ELF binary, there is a hint if the used compiler is mentioned somewhere.